# Linear Algebra Matrix Transformation Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Can someone please help me out with this question. If a nonzero matrix $A$ is transformed from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the null space of $A$ must be a one dimensional (sub)space of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So i know that null space of $A$ is $\{x \colon Ax=0\}$ and I also know the definition of not onto. I don't understand the whole concept of one-dimensional space and would this statement be always true?

Comment: You should learn math markup (most of LaTeX can be used), and you should ask questions with defined terms. Your question, as it stands, is very difficult to read!}

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694270/understanding-2nd-half-rank-nullity-theorem-proof.