# Understanding 2nd half rank-nullity theorem proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification

I'm trying to understand the second half of the rank-nullity theorem (the part that shows $T(e_{k+1}) \dots T(e_{k+r})$ is independent).

Assume $e_1 ,\dots e_k, e_{k+1}, \dots e_{k+r}$,is a basis for $V$ where $k+r = n$. $n = dim(V)$. $T$ is a linear transformation from linear space $V$ to linear space $W$.

The first step in the proof is to show that $T(e_{k+1}), \dots T(e_{k+r})$ spans $T(V)$. I understand this part of the proof.

I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning why $T(e_{k+1}), \dots T(e_{k+r})$ is independent.

Here goes:

Let $\sum_{i= k+1}^{k+r}a_iT(e_i)$ = 0, for appropriate choice of scalars. Then
we know that $T(\sum_{i= k+1}^{k+r}a_ie_i) = 0$ since T is a linear transformation. Thus, we know that there is an element $z = a_{k+1}e_{k+1} + \dots + a_{k+r}e_{k+r}$. $z$ is in the null space so $z$ can be written as $a_{1}e_{1} + \dots + a_{k}e_{k}$. If we subtract the two we get:

(*) $z-z =\sum_{i= 1}^{k}a_ie_i - \sum_{i= k+1}^{k+r}a_ie_i$ = 0.

Since we said that $e_1 ,\dots e_k, e_{k+1}, \dots e_{k+r}$ is a basis for $V$, and hence independent, the $a_i$'s must be 0.

The next line in the proof says:(*This is where I am lost*)
"Therefore, the elements in $T(e_{k+1}) \dots T(e_{k+r})$ are independent."

The reasoning seems to be: since "e_{k+1}, \dots e_{k+r}" is independent then $T(e_{k+1}) \dots T(e_{k+r})$ is independent. But I don't see why that is the case.

I have a strong suspicion that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What is the dimension of $T(V)$?

Comment: Read the first sentence after “Here goes” again. With this setup, what do you need to show to establish the independence?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I need to establish that when $a_iT(e_i)$ = 0, every $a_i$ is forced to 0.

Comment: And this is exactly how the passage that you have quoted ends.

Comment: Informally: This is possible because whenever you write a linear interdependence between $\{Te_i\}_{i=k+1}^{k+r}$ you can ensure that all the $a_i$ must be zero, as you did above. But this is just the definition of linear independence. Done.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Okay. I think I get it. Another question: is it wrong to conclude that the argument is saying: if $e_a ... e_z$ is independent, then $T(e_a) ... T(e_z)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Suppose the zero transformation then $Te_i$'s are linearly dependent. In order to ensure that the $\{Te_i\}_{i\in I}$ be linearly independent whenever  $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is, it's necessary an extra hypothesis. In this case the linear transformation needs to be injective. If $T$ is 1-1 then its kernel is trivial $\ker=\{0\}$ and so if we write a linear interdependence we have $\sum_{i\in I} a_iTe_i=0$, by linearity $T \sum_{i\in I} a_i e_i=0$ then $\sum_{i\in I} a_i e_i\in \ker T$. But this means that $\sum_{i\in I} a_i e_i =0$ and by linear independence of $e_i$'s all the $a_i=0$.